# Qt QProcess::kill() not kill the process

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qprocess

I develop a GUI app in Qt.

This runs a Python program, with QProcess.
In `myapp.h` file is the pr def:

```
QProcess *pr = new QProcess(this);
```

In constructor is this:

```
QString file = "program/path.py";
pr->start("[...]/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe", QStringList() << file);
```

And the destructor have this code:

```
pr->kill();
delete ui;
```

If I run this program, I don't have errors. I close the window, but this process still run, but I don't know why.

I'm working in Windows.

Comment: `QProcess::kill()` uses `TerminateProcess` on Windows. I would say that your code doesn't run. Did you check with a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

I test this example and kill() works.

Maybe your process already was started in your system and the start function didn't work correctly.

Try this :
I have 2 pushbuttons for the start and kill the process :

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QProcess>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui
{
class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void  on_pb_start_clicked();

    void  on_pb_kill_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QProcess       *pr;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void  MainWindow::on_pb_start_clicked()
{
    pr = new QProcess(this);

    pr->start("vlc");
}

void  MainWindow::on_pb_kill_clicked()
{
    pr->kill();
}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks your long help! I tested this, and it's working with vlc, or PuTTY. But with python code it isn't. So I think the problem is in python, for exmaple in exceptions. I'm trying here.